# Android chat application anonymous Login with meeting url using Skype for Business

Tags: android, skype-for-business

I have to make an android chat application using Skype for business . I have however extracted meeting URL. I have been following the microsoft documentation but now i am struck at anonymous login . The link for the documentation  is this 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/anonymousmeetingjoin

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/howtojoinmeeting_android

I am not able to implement this i dont know what i am missing .I need help in this very much

Comment: I would hope you are using the [App SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/skypeappsdk) as that will have information on how to make use of a targeted library for Android.and take a look at the [P2P Anon Join Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/P2PAnonymousChat/P2PAnonChat)

Comment: I have integrated sdk according to the documentation although on running the sample application it gives FAILED to Load Native Libraries error!! i jst cant find a solution to this thing